# Show Newton's method can go wrong with two roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, roots

If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable with at least two roots, I wish to show that Newton's method will not converge for some $x_0$.

I know that $f'(x)$ has a zero, say  at $z$.  It seems we should choose $x_0$ close to $z$ to ensure that the Newton iterates wander away.  But it's hard to say anything more precise without knowing more about $f(x)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f'(x_0) = 0$, there is no $x_1$.
In the case of a quadratic $f$ with two real roots, that is the only initial point where Newton goes wrong: for all other $x_0$, it converges to one of the roots.

EDIT: Somewhat more generally, if $f$ is a convex differentiable function with at least one root, you have convergence to a root from any $x_0$ with $f'(x_0) \ne 0$.

Comment: So then the question is either trivial or wrong?  I had interpreted "not converge" to mean that the iterates exist but don't converge.

Comment: @TorsionSquid I think that's Robert's answer is correct, complete, and that your interpretation is a bit too much.  Consider, for example, $f(x)=x^2-1$.  Newton's method will converge to 1 for all positive choices of initial seed $x_0$ and will converge to -1 for all negative choices of $x_0$. The only initial seed where we do not have convergence is $x_0=\infty$, where we have a division by zero.

Comment: Ok.  I guess I was expecting the problem to be harder than noting that $f'$ has a zero.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this example:
$$x^3 - 5x = 0$$
$$x_0=1$$

Comment: So I should look for periodic orbits of the Newton map?

Comment: @TorsionSquid Are you trying to prove that for all $f(x)$ there is some $x_0$ that will cause it not to converge? or for some $f(x)$ there is some $x_0$ that will cause it not to converge?

(I read it as the latter)

Comment: I wish to show it for all $f(x)$ with at least two roots.